# How to keep selected item in a spinner selected until the user select different item..?

Tags: java, android

I have 3 activities (Main_apage, second_page, and settings_page). and in the setting page I have a spinner filled with a few colors where the user can choose from. so, what I want to do is, when the user select one color, let's say "RED", I want the selected item to remain the same (which is "RED" unless changed by the user.

I tried shared preference to save the selected item and to retrieve the stored item but it didn't seem to work for me.

// settings_page class

```
    public class Settings_page extends AppCompatActivity
 {
    private Spinner colors;
    private Button done_button;

    private List<String> color_list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private int chosen_color;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefer;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_page);
        
        lang_list.add("Green");
        lang_list.add("Red");
        lang_list.add("Blue");
        lang_list.add("Yellow");
        lang_list.add("Black");
        lang_list.add("White");
        lang_list.add("Purple");
        lang_list.add("Pink");

        colors = findViewById(R.id.col);
        sharedPrefer = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = sharedPrefer.edit();

    


        ArrayAdapter<String> color_andpter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, color_list);
     
        colors.setAdapter(lang_andpter);
      

colors.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                editor.PutInt("color", position);
                editor.commit();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
        });


done_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int def_value = 0;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings_page.this, Main_page.class);
                chosen_color = sharedPrefer.getString("color", 0);
                intent.putExtra("language", chosen_color);
                startActivityForResult(intent, def_value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

// Main class

```
public class Main_page extends AppCompatActivity
{
   private Button secondPage;

    //to store selected items from setting_page
    private int selected_color;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        secondPage= findViewById(R.id.sec);
       

        //retrieves selected value from settings_page
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        selected_color = intent.getIntExtra("color", 0);
       
secondPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int def_value = 0;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main_page.this, Second_page.class);
                intent.putExtra("col", selected_color);
                startActivityForResult(intent, def_value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

//second_page class

```
public class Second_page extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    private TextView textView ;
 
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //retrieves selected value from Main page
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int color = intent.getIntExtra("col", 0);

       textView.setText(String.valueOf(color));
    }
}
```

Let's say the user selected "Pink" which is index 7. When I exit out of setting page and go to second page it display 7. Which is what I wanted. The problem comes when I exit out of second page and go back to second page again always displays 0 though the user hasn't change the setting.

Comment: Can you make this part clear: _" when i exit out of second page and go back to second page again"_ ? It will be better if you add the order of your activities being opened.

Comment: Change this line editor.PutInt("color", position); to editor.putString("color", lang_list.get(position));

Answer (score 0):

As, you are using sharedPreferences, using `intent.getIntExtra()` or `intent.putExtra()` is completely unnecessary. Also there's a huge chance that the value that are added with intent can be destroyed when that activity restarts.

So, to solve this you don't need to put something with the intent, just fetch the value that are already saved in your `sharedPreferences`.

**Let's Solve this step by step**

1. > remove this code snippet from both of your `settings_page` & `main_page` as you saved the value of your chosen color in shared preferences, you don't need to pass the value using intent.

   ```
   chosen_color = sharedPrefer.getString("color", 0);
   intent.putExtra("color", chosen_color);
   ```
2. > Remove this code from your `second_page`

   ```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   int color = intent.getIntExtra("col", 0);
   ```
3. > Use this code in your `second_page` to fetch your already saved chosen_color from sharedPreferences

   ```
   sharedPrefer = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   int color = sharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0);
   ```
4. > And now use this index to fetch the actual color from your `lang_list` and set it in the textview

   ```
   String colorValue = lang_list.get(color);
   textView.setText(String.valueOf(colorValue));
   ```